# s3のIP制御について

Tags: aws, amazon-s3

S3で画像を管理しているのですが、IPを制限して自分のサーバーからのみアクセス許可をしたいのですが、設定のconditionの中にIPを入れると403が返ってきてアクセスできません。conditionを外すと表示されます。

具体的に設定方法や確認すべき箇所、(あれば)必要なコマンドなどご教示いただけますでしょうか？

よろしくお願い致します。

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1527266936788",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt11111111,
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxx/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx/24"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: 「自分のサーバー」とはEC2だったりしますか？

Comment: いえ、EC2ではありません。GMOのサーバーです。

Answer (score 3):

[特定の IP アドレスへのアクセスの制限](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-3)にも例がある通りであり、質問文に記載された範囲では問題なさそうです。１点、質問文に記載されていない範囲で気になりました。[IPアドレス条件演算子](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_IPAddress)の説明に

> IP アドレス条件演算子では、キーと IPv4 または IPv6 アドレスまたは IP アドレス範囲の比較に基づいてアクセスを制限する Condition 要素を構築できます。 これらを aws:SourceIp キーと合わせて使用します。値は、**標準的な CIDR 形式でなければいけません** (例 : 203.0.113.0/24 または 2001:DB8:1234:5678::/64)。

とあります。`"xx.xx.xxx.xxx/24"` と値が伏せられていますが24bit CIDRであれば `"xx.xx.xxx.0/24"` とする必要があります。標準的な CIDR 形式を設定していますでしょうか？